# CSS layers - I can't get one element on top of another one

Tags: html, css

I have there a registration form where all elements have `z-index` between -5 and -15.

And it's on top of everything, even though other elements have z-index between -5 and -2 (I want them to be over the form, their `z-index` had to be below zero only because otherwise the shadows get messed up).

The `z-index` for the `body` is -10.

Comment: `z-index` only applies to elements whose position is not static.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting following id's z-index to

```
.login-noh![enter image description here][1]over-linkbox{padding:10px;z-index:12;}

#login-hover-cont{width:210px;padding:20px;position:absolute;right:0px;_right:1px;top:15px;z-index:5;background:#fff}
```

[image]